# A way to send Direct Message to all Server Members? Java Discord Api

Tags: java, discord-jda

I wanted to script a command to send an Private Message to all Server Members, is that possible?
I know how to send a DM to the Author of the message but not to all Server Members.

Comment: Yes, you can fetch every guild-member and send message to them by looping through them. BTW which lib are you using JDA or Discord4J?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu JDA=Java Discord Api.

Comment: @KlemensMorbe yep

Comment: If you implement any listener, check the event. The event has an JDA instance and this has a list of all guild/server members. See https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html

Comment: Lol I did not asked the question xDD

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, suppose you have your target server's ID, with that you can call on your bot's jda instance

```
jda.getGuildById(<ID>);
```

Or if you just have the name, it's also possible with

```
jda.getGuildsByName(<NAME>, <CASE_SENSITIVE>)
```

The name one will return a list with all the matching names, this is quite impractical, since getting the ID is so easy.

You might have gotten your `Guild` object some other way (Through a listener maybe?), it does not matter.

Now you can either call `guild.getMembers()` or `guild.getMemberCache()` which one should you choose? 
`guild.getMemberCache()` is, by default more efficient and in the end it implements the `Iterable` interface, so for all your intents and purposes, it should be better to use `getMemberCache()`, the benefit of `getMembers()` is that you'll get it as a list, making is trivial to do more processing.

Now you have your `List<Member>` or `MemberCacheView`, let's iterate through it
here the simplest option is the `forEach()` method, or just a for each loop:

```
for (Member member : guild.getMemberCache())
```

Or:

```
guild.getMemberCache().forEach(member -> <DO_SOMETHING>)
```

(If you choose to use `guild.getMembers()` it would be exactly the same)

Now to actually send your messages:

Remember we are iterating over `Member` objects, but JDA does not allow us to open private channels through that, so we need

```
PrivateChannel channel = member.getUser().openPrivateChannel().complete();
```

Note that here you need to either wait for the synchronous `complete()` and receive the `PrivateChannel` object normally, or you can pass a consumer to the queue method when opening the `PrivateChannel`, which will be executed as soon as the channel is available:

```
Consumer<PrivateChannel> messageSender = channel -> channel.sendMessage("Hey~~!").queue();
user.openPrivateChannel().queue(messageSender);
```

Or:

```
user.openPrivateChannel().queue(channel -> channel.sendMessage("Hey~~!").queue());
```

Now we have the channel and sending a message is simple

```
channel.sendMessage("Hey~~!").queue();
```

So putting it all together we get:

```
Guild guild; //Guild you got from a listener, or from the JDA pool

for(Member member : guild.getMemberCache()) { //Iterating over cached members in the guild
   User user = member.getUser(); //Converting the member object to a User

  user.openPrivateChannel().queue(channel->
             channel.sendMessage("Hey~~!").queue()); //Opening the channel and sending the message

   /*  Now you can optionally close the channel to remove it from the JDA's mapping */
   channel.close().queue();
}
```